# Is the “are” in this sentence ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english

Is the “are” in this sentence ungrammatical?

> ​‎How do you feel about some people are calling you "Toma-chan" in
>   Japan?

Comment: Hello Cody. What has caused you to think it could be ungrammatical? Why do you think it could be? Please see [how to ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - one of our requirements is to include the research you have done.

Comment: Compare this obviously ungrammatical sentence: _I worry about some people are staring at me._

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as written is not correct.

You can change it to:

> How do you feel about some people calling you "Toma-chan" in Japan?

(with *are* removed)

or

> How do you feel *that* some people are calling you "Toma-chan" in Japan?

These both ask your opinion about the fact that some people are calling you "Toma-chan". I don't know the name for the grammatical rules that govern these forms of the question.

Another possible rewording is:

> How do you feel about the people *who* are calling you "Toma-chan" in Japan?

This asks your opinion of the people, not the situation.

Another possibility is:

> How do you feel about the people calling you "Toma-chan" in Japan?

But this is ambiguous, it could mean the same thing as either of the earlier variations. Context could make the intent clear, though.